# Hide white space when visibility set on row

Tags: reporting-services

I am hoping to eliminate extra white space between groupings. I have a report with details that are suppressed if the `GroupBy` for the Property parameter is `Yes`. The problem is that it shows rows in between the groups.

```
=IIF(Parameters!GroupBy.Value="Property",True,False)
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Set the visibility of the row with that value as well, or are you doing that already?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do something like Below:

1. Go to Row which you wish to Hide
2. Right click and go to Row Visibility
3. Then give IIF condition as visibility Criteria.

   =IIF(Parameters!Property.Value="Yes",True,False)
4. This will Hide your extra rows when Parameter property is set as Yes.

Just for simple checking you could bydefault hide extra row without any condition and see if this works.
Then you could go step by step.